# CSS: Height in a previous DIV is pushing down the footer with Clear:Both

Tags: css

I'm having an issue where I have a min-height set up in a div above the footer. In order to get the text in the footer to align center, I am using clear:both in the CSS. The only issue is that now there is a large space between the content and the footer?

Here's the site I'm working on:
http://brimbar.com/no_crawl/RiverHollow/about.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have that floated image with the giant `margin-bottom`. `clear: both` means "no elements should be on either side of this element", so the footer has to be below that 600px margin.

The reason that the footer text isn't centered without `clear: both` is because it's only centering within the width between the start of the div and the left side of that image (plus its giant margin).

What you should do is change the markup so that your image appears in another column div inside the content div, since you seem to want to display it in its own column rather than floated.  If you do this, you won't need the giant margin, nor will you need `clear: both` on your footer elements.

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/uxiqer/1/edit

Note you can use floats or `position: absolute` to position the `.images` div on right; I just find `position: absolute` easier to work with.

If you don't need images to display in their own column then you can simply keep the float on the image and remove that `margin-bottom`, then the text will wrap nicely around the image and its margin. This is the intended purpose of `float`. Then without the giant margin overflowing the content div, the footer text can be centered properly without any need for `clear: both`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the clear: both and add a specific height to the footer not just min-height. I can't get your text to align but I bet it would if you removed "position:static" on it.

Since you hard-coded the 1550px height on the container itself, the footer is taking up the rest of the space available to it since it only has a "minimum-height" requirement not max.